# What is the problem with my Rsync command?

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to make a rsync but when I write

```
"rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh -p port_number" /abc/def/ghi user@IP:/jkl/mno"
```

I have this following error `"rsync: change_dir "/abc/def" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Where does the problem come from?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [superuser](https://superuser.com) or the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) would be better places to ask about this. But first, are you sure the path is correct? Does /abc/def/ghi (or whatever you actually used) exist on the local computer?

Comment: Oh, ok sorry ! Yes my path is correct and this is weird

Comment: It's not as simple as getting the file paths wrong. The intent here is to rsync over a specified ssh port (not 22). You want to rsync using ssh forwarding. The port number as such is misleading and yields confusing errors.